# Which babel plugin is declaring this var?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, babeljs, formidable

I'm trying to start `auth0-lock` this [electron project](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate).

In one of auth0's nested dependencides (`node-formidable`), there's this line at the top of a file:

```
if (global.GENTLY) require = GENTLY.hijack(require);
```

This is something they use for testing to overwrite global require, but setting `global.GENTLY` to false should bypass it for development mode.

However, something in the webpack/babel configs (below) in this project is changing this line to this:

```
var require;if (global.GENTLY) require = GENTLY.hijack(require);
```

This is overwriting the global `require` & breaking the rest of the file/build with `require is not a function`

I'm going through the plugins 1-by-1 to find what's doing this, but so far nothing doing.

Anyone know what setting would cause this overwrite?

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": { "node": 6 },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports", "dynamic-import-webpack"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["react-optimize"],
      "plugins": ["babel-plugin-dev-expression"]
    },
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-es2015-classes",
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        ["flow-runtime", {
          "assert": true,
          "annotate": true
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}


// webpack config

/* eslint global-require: 0, import/no-dynamic-require: 0 */

/**
 * Build config for development electron renderer process that uses
 * Hot-Module-Replacement
 *
 * https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/
 */

import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import { spawn, execSync } from 'child_process';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;
const publicPath = `http://localhost:${port}/dist`;
const dll = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dll');
const manifest = path.resolve(dll, 'vendor.json');

/**
 * Warn if the DLL is not built
 */
if (!(fs.existsSync(dll) && fs.existsSync(manifest))) {
  console.log(chalk.black.bgYellow.bold(
    'The DLL files are missing. Sit back while we build them for you with "npm run build-dll"'
  ));
  execSync('npm run build-dll');
}

export default merge.smart(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  target: 'electron-renderer',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${port}/`,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.js'),
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${port}/dist/`
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      // Add SASS support  - compile all .global.scss files and pipe it to style.css
      {
        test: /\.global\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      // Add SASS support  - compile all other .scss files and pipe it to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      // WOFF Font
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          }
        },
      },
      // WOFF2 Font
      {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          }
        }
      },
      // TTF Font
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
          }
        }
      },
      // EOT Font
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      // SVG Font
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
          }
        }
      },
      // Common Image Formats
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        use: 'url-loader',
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: process.cwd(),
      manifest: require(manifest),
      sourceType: 'var',
    }),

    /**
     * https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/
     */
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
      // @TODO: Waiting on https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/533
      // multiStep: true
    }),

    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

    /**
     * Create global constants which can be configured at compile time.
     *
     * Useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and
     * release builds
     *
     * NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain
     * development checks
     *
     * By default, use 'development' as NODE_ENV. This can be overriden with
     * 'staging', for example, by changing the ENV variables in the npm scripts
     */
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }),

    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true
    }),

    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    port,
    publicPath,
    compress: true,
    noInfo: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    inline: true,
    lazy: false,
    hot: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 100
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
      verbose: true,
      disableDotRule: false,
    },
    setup() {
      if (process.env.START_HOT) {
        spawn(
          'npm',
          ['run', 'start-hot-renderer'],
          { shell: true, env: process.env, stdio: 'inherit' }
        )
        .on('close', code => process.exit(code))
        .on('error', spawnError => console.error(spawnError));
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it by adding this plugin to my webpack config (webpack v4):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'global.GENTLY': false })
```

Hopefully they'll release formidable@2 soon with the fix.